# Drawing up a session value within SQL query? PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, syntax, string

on one of my web pages I want my manager user to view all activities assigned to them (personally). In order to do this, I need something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE manager = $_SESSION['SESS_FULLNAME']";
```

Now obviously this syntax is all wrong, but because I am new to this stuff, is there a way I can call up the full name from the user's session within a query? This is so that when I call up the database values to be displayed within the web page, only the activities for the manager who is logged in is displayed. For example, the activities table has a manager column of a full name entry. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE manager = '".$_SESSION['SESS_FULLNAME']."'";
```

To use a variables in a query you should use quote...

use `'` to define a string in query..

ie.
if manager is a number use 
`WHERE manager = ".$_SESSION['SESS_FULLNAME']` (without ')
if manager is a string
`WHERE manager = '".$_SESSION['SESS_FULLNAME']."'`

Comment: You are my hero (until I run into my next problem!) Thank you so much for this.

Comment: Note that a string literal must be escaped using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @Derek Please take Col. Shrapnel's advice and don't include unescaped strings in your query. See also: SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you do not have to "leave" the string. You can more easily do this:

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM activities WHERE manager = {$_SESSION['SESS_FULLNAME']}";`

See [PHP's double-quoted string syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) for more info.

That said, please use either [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) or escaped variables (in that order of preference) when dealing with dynamic parameters.